# Script to suspend USB no longer works

Tags: hardware

I have a script which suspends the usb, which was working until a recent update, and no longer works.

The code used to suspend is:

```
echo 1 > /sys/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/bussuspend
```

It returns error:

```
bash: /sys/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb/bussuspend: No such file or directory
```

output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux xxxxxx 4.1.7+ #817 PREEMPT Sat Sep 19 15:25:36 BST 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

After this update I had to put a line into `config.txt` to enable I2C , is there something I need to do to enable the ability to suspend usb or is there another problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

On further research, it appears that the with my latest update the usb bus is no longer `/sys/devices/platform/bcm2708_usb` but `/sys/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb`

I found this by running `dmesg | grep usb`

This alone didn't solve my problem as the usbsuspend didn't work, I had to use usbpower to disable the usb, with the following command;

```
sudo sh -c "echo 0 > /sys/devices/platform/soc/20980000.usb/buspower"
```

(to re-enable change the 0 to 1)

Hopefully this will help someone.

Comment: It helped me! I have changed some of my own SE answers to make use of this "new" information. Thanks.